# How did Dennis Creevey get his Hogwarts acceptance letter?

Tags: harry-potter, hogwarts

Dennis Creevey, Colin Creevey’s little brother, started his first year at Hogwarts in *Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire.*

Muggle-borns get their letters from a special messenger, who can tell the family about the Wizarding world and that their child is magical and will attend Hogwarts.

Given that the Creevey family already know about the Wizarding world via Colin receiving **his** letter, would they use owl post to send Dennis’s letter (as is normal for pure and half-bloods)?

Comment: hard to say, Dennis is barely even referenced on wizardingworld.com and the article that does mention him links to a 404 page :|

Comment: im sure it would come by post

Answer (score 20, accepted):

#### Presumably it’d come by owl, or regular, post.

While there is no known specific case showing how a second Muggleborn in a family receives their Hogwarts letter, in the case of a wizard living with Muggles who already know about magic, the letter comes by owl post. Harry lived with Muggles who already knew about magic before he was supposed to attend Hogwarts, and his letter, plus several subsequent letters, arrived on their own. No one arrived with any of the letters to explain the wizarding world to the Dursleys.

> “Three things lay on the doormat: a postcard from Uncle Vernon’s sister Marge, who was holidaying on the Isle of Wight, a brown envelope that looked like a bill and – a letter for Harry.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone, Chapter 3 (The Letters from No One)*</sup></sub>

Hagrid only went to see Harry in person when it was clear Harry was being prevented from reading his letters. While they did not, it was assumed that the Dursleys would have told him about Hogwarts and that he was a wizard.

> “Call me Hagrid,’ he said, ‘everyone does. An’ like I told yeh, I’m Keeper of Keys at Hogwarts – yeh’ll know all about Hogwarts, o’ course.’
>
> ‘Er – no,’ said Harry.
>
> Hagrid looked shocked.
>
> ‘Sorry,’ Harry said quickly.
>
> ‘Sorry?’ barked Hagrid, turning to stare at the Dursleys, who shrank back into the shadows. ‘It’s them as should be sorry! I knew yeh weren’t gettin’ yer letters but I never thought yeh wouldn’t even know abou’ Hogwarts, fer cryin’ out loud! Did yeh never wonder where yer parents learnt it all?” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone, Chapter 4 (The Keeper of the Keys)*</sup></sub>

Presumably in the case of parents who already know about magic through an older child, the letter would similarly arrive by owl as they are already aware that the wizarding world exists.

Comment: Notably, Creevy Sr. would have received his second and third year letters by owl post, so there would be a semi-regular delivery to the house

Comment: not to mention the likely daily letters and photos Colin would have been sending his first year lol

Comment: +1 for the "several subsequent letters" understatement